# Auto create sheets based on data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 1200 products, divided into approximately 100 categories. I need to review the prices on every single product.

Doing this manually will be incredibly time consuming, but with this calculator I have made it will take some of the pain out of the process, but I want to take it even further.

Here is my calculator:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P_2AaikhOr64SRVrHeCVvMpYzSGeklzxtkxDaZpqcFI/edit#gid=1573240572

The data I will feed it is in the Royal Blue cells (L2:L8)

With this data I can quickly see a guideline of prices based on the weight of one item, how many will fit into a parcel, the cost price and minimum price and target profit, etc.

> What I would dearly like to do is feed an entire categories' worth of
>   data into a sheet, and then it automatically creates X identical tabs
>   based on this data.
>
> I could copy and paste this data in one go into a sheet, in an ideal scenario. Perhaps the tabs could be named according to the product code too.

I would then end up with 100 or so sheets, instead of 1200!

I don't know if this is possible, and I don't know where to start looking for ideas or examples of this, can anyone point me in the right direction or show me how I could do this, please?

Comment: Could you give reading permissions to your sheet? We cannot access it. It's definitely possible using the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class.

Comment: oops, done that now. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm struggling to understand the context of this. I guess this sheet is one of your ~1200 products, so you have a sheet for each one (1200 sheets then) and you want group them in a single spreadsheet with ~100 tabs in it. Those tabs are categories and contain the L2:L8 data of 1200 products. I took a look at your sheet but I don't see any 'Category' or any field to order by.